# Change detection for child property in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-changedetection

I have the following Product object inside an Angular application. The product contains array of orders and other product information.

**Product.ts**

```
export interface Product { 
    ProductID: number;
    ProductName: string;
    Orders: Order[]
}
```

I need to display product information and generate order summary inside a child angular component.

**order-summary.component.ts**

```
export class OrderSummary {

  _product: Product;
  @Input() set product(value: Product) {
    this._product = value;
    this.generateOrderSummary(value.Orders);
  }

  private generateOrderSummary(orders: Order[]) {
   // Logic to generate order summary
  }

}
```

**order-summary.component.html**

```
<b>{{_product.ProductName}}</b>
<b> ... show other product details </b>
<table> ... show generated order summary ... </table>
```

I believe every time the product object changes, it will generate the order summary (`generateOrderSummary`) even if the `Orders` array hasn't been changed. What is a better way to fix this issue?

I am thinking of adding another property for Orders[] so I can regenerate summary only when order has been changed. However, product already contains orders not sure if it is a good design.

**order-summary.component.ts**

```
export class OrderSummary {
  _product: Product;
  @Input() set product(value: Product) {
    this._product = value;
  }

  @Input() set orders(value: Orders[]) {
    this.generateOrderSummary(value.Orders);
  }

  private generateOrderSummary(orders: Order[]) {
   // Logic to generate order summary
  }
}
```

Are there any better solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you could skip the setter implementation of the `@Input` and use Angular [`OnChanges`](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges) hook with [`SimpleChanges`](https://angular.io/api/core/SimpleChanges) parameter. It allows you to check if it's the first invoke of the component and compare previous and current values of the `@Input` property.

Try the following

**order-summary.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

export class OrderSummary implements OnChanges {
  @Input() product: Product;

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (!!changes.product) {
      if (changes.product.firstChange) {                 // <-- first time the component is rendered
        this.generateOrderSummary(this.product.orders);  // <-- could also be `changes.product.currentValue.orders`
      } else if (                                        // <-- true only if different `orders` value
        !!changes.product.previousValue &&
        !!changes.product.previousValue.orders &&
        changes.product.previousValue.orders !== changes.product.currentValue.orders
      ) {
        this.generateOrderSummary(product.orders);
      }
    }
  }

  private generateOrderSummary(orders: Order[]) {
    // Logic to generate order summary
  }
}
```

**order-summary.component.html**

```html
<b>{{ product?.ProductName }}</b>
<b> ... show other product details </b>
<table> ... show generated order summary ... </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use observables and rxjs logic like this.

```
export class OrderSummary implements OnInit {
  product$: Observable<Product>;
  private productSubject$ = new Subject();

  @Input() set product(value: Product) {
    this.productSubject$.next(value);
  }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.product$ = this.productSubject$.pipe(
          distinctUntilChanged((prev: Product, curr: Product) => prev.ProductId === curr.ProductId), 
          map(prod => {
             this.generateOrderSummary(prod.orders);
             return prod;
          })
  }


  private generateOrderSummary(orders: Order[]) {
   // Logic to generate order summary
  }

}
```

and subscribe to product in your html

```
<div *ngIf="product$ | async as product">
   <b>{{product.ProductName}}</b>
   <b> ... show other product details </b>
   <table> ... show generated order summary ... </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Lautaro, I do not want to call generateOrderSummary when product name or other product properties change. How does it make sure it does not generateOrderSummary when product name change?

Comment: the method generateOrderSummary will be called only when the product id change (different product). distinctUntilChanged make the map not execute when product id is equals

Comment: The product id will always remain the same. Other properties inside the product object may change.

Comment: I think I can tweak the logic to make it work so thanks for your help too.